# SCSS - Lighten/Darken do not compile?

Tags: css, sass

In my main file `styles.scss` I have declared a variable:

```
$primary  : #1e4f9c;
$change   : 15%;
```

Then I import another SCSS file:

```
@import "/project-assets/css/layout.scss";
```

In that file I create CSS variables:

```
:root {
    --primary: #{$primary};
    --primary-light: lighten(#{$primary}, #{$change});
    --primary-dark: darken(#{$primary}, #{$change});
}
```

but for some reason the output here is not the new HEX values but the function call stays as it is:

```
:root {
    --primary: #1e4f9c;
    --primary-light: lighten(#1e4f9c, 15%);
    --primary-dark: darken(#1e4f9c, 15%);
}
```

[image]

I found out that lighten function doesn't work as expected with percentage and changed it to `color.scale` but the output is still in SCSS not changed into a HEX. What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Css variables can store only static values, not functions ? Try this instead:

```
$primary: #1e4f9c;
$change: 15%;
:root {
  --primary: #{$primary};
  --primary-light: #{lighten($primary, $change)};
  --primary-dark: #{darken($primary, $change)};
}
```

Comment: I wasn't trying to store functions. I just thought that `darken` is SCSS function and will be executed at compile time and replaced with hex. I suspect I'm wrong but can't understand why..

Comment: Yes i see. It seems that the issue has nothing to do with css variables in the end. At least in the online scss playground.  This syntax with `#{}` interpolation in `scss` function is not compiling at all: `lighten(#{$primary}, #{$change});`  Even if added directly to css property without variables. I'm not sure what is happening under the hood.

Comment: @protob I think the reason you need to interpolate the whole `#{lighten($primary, $change)}` is to tell "that whole function is to be interpreted as scss, not just the variables"

Comment: Sounds reasonable.